# Why is this gap coming between the li tags? Please see my code

Tags: html, css

Please see this css and html and then see the image to understand the gaps that i am talking about. I am probably fussing over something too small, and getting this fixed won't have any effect on the webpage's usability, but i am learning right now, and i just want to understand this behaviour.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/resetdefault.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <nav id="navmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Sample</li>
                <li>Sample</li>
                <li>Sample</li>
                <li>Sample</li>
                <li>Sample</li>
                <li>Sample</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="login.html">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two css files attached, one is my reset file the other is for this page:

Reset CSS:

```
 html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr,
 acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike,
 strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label,
 legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details,
 embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
 time, mark, audio, video, input, select
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    word-wrap:normal;
    }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
    }
body {
    line-height: 1.2;
    }
ol {
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: decimal;
    }
ul {
    list-style: square;
    }
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    }
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
a{
    color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
a:active{
    color:inherit;
    }
input[type="submit"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

main file (For this page):

```
    #navmenu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;
}

#navmenu ul{
    display:inline-block;
}

#topbar a {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}

#navmenu {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#navmenu ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Now this is a image of my nav menu in the browser, notice the gaps in between the li elements. I have changed the display property, i have checked in chrome if this is some kind of margin, but when i do inspect element, it doesn't really tell me what the gap is.

[image]

Comment: Ya, even i didn't understand why he needs that, but ive added anyway.

Comment: `float: left;` in `#navmenu ul li`

Comment: I now get how to get rid of this, but still have no idea why this happens! The duplicate question, only talks about solutions to this problem. Why is this gap there??

Comment: @Sam1604 You should create a proper answer so that it can be marked in the future, this time though emmanuel beat you to it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Floating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) `li` elements `left` will remove the gap between them:

```
#navmenu ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Lol, this answer is much better than any of the top answers in the duplicate question. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just checked the post and there is one similar there too. You are welcome!